# for loop django template tag using context

Tags: python, django

I am trying to query all Restaurants and show them to the user  in my model but i can't get the template to show the items in the model

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Featured Restraunts</h1>
<ul>

{% for restaurant in restaurants %}
    <li><h2>{{ restaurants.name }}</h2></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}

this is what i get
Featured Restaurants



and this is my views.py
def view_restaurants(request):
    restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all()
    return render(request,'menu/restaurants.html',{"restaurants":"restaurants",},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

is it a spelling mistake, All I want is to see a list of restaurants.

if I remove .name after restraunt my browser shows

restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants
restaurants

even though there are only 2 entries

Comment: Try: `<li><h2>{{ restaurant.name }}</h2></li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quotation marks around the `restaurants` variable (and you don't need the comma either) -

```
return render(request,'menu/restaurants.html', {"restaurants": restaurants})
```

Also `render` doesn't require you to set the `context_instance`.

Answer (score 1):

```
{"restaurants":"restaurants",}
```

seems to be your problem